# Remove Border of a BitBtn

Tags: c++, border, vcl

I am using CodeGear 2007 and have a VCL Application. 
I just wondered if there is a way to remove the border of my BitBtns, so I can only see the Glyph without the border and the background of the button.

Already tried a few things with the HWnd control but its a bit complicated for me to fully understand all the settings I have to make.

```
HWND WINAPI CreateWindow(
    _In_opt_ LPCTSTR   BS_OWNERDRAW,
    _In_opt_ LPCTSTR   lpWindowName,
    _In_     DWORD     dwStyle,
    _In_     int       x,
    _In_     int       y,
    _In_     int       nWidth,
    _In_     int       nHeight,
    _In_opt_ HWND      hWndParent,
    _In_opt_ HMENU     hMenu,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ LPVOID    lpParam
);
```

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a transparent `TImage` instead of `TBitBtn`. If you don't want the visuals of a button, then why are you using a button at all?

Comment: Thats a good idea never thought about that, guess was just too focused getting this borderless thing done . I will try it to see if it does what i want :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the 2007 version but in the C++ BUILDER 10 and further versions you can directly create your own style or redesign your VCL component using the `BitmapStyleDesigner.exe` tool that you can find in the bin directory. You can do pretty much anything like change the standard images of the buttons and remove the borders of course.

https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/customizing-and-creating-vcl-styles-671